CSP Header Nonce is not showing up after adding it in next.config.mjs?
New to CSP headers :
I'm working on a nextjs application
I have added this csp in middleware.ts

const nonce = Buffer.from(crypto.randomUUID()).toString('base64')


const cspHeader = `
default-src 'self' https://www.google.com/ https://test.com https://*.stripe.com;
script-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}' 'strict-dynamic' https://test.com https://*.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com;
style-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}' https://test.com https://*.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com;
connect-src 'self' https://test.com https://*.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com;
img-src 'self' blob: data:;
font-src 'self';
object-src 'none';
base-uri 'self';
form-action 'self';
frame-ancestors 'none';
upgrade-insecure-requests;
`

This shows a nonce in the script tag but there is not csp added in the request headers checked the network tag throughly

And when I try to add the CSP in next.config.mjs

const cspHeader = `
  default-src 'self' https://www.google.com/ https://test.com https://*.stripe.com;
  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://test.com https://*.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com;
  connect-src 'self' https://test.com https://*.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com;
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://test.com https://*.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com;
  img-src 'self' blob: data:;
  font-src 'self';
  object-src 'none';
  base-uri 'self';
  form-action 'self';
  frame-ancestors 'none';
  upgrade-insecure-requests;
`

It shows up in the network tab
When i use the script-src 'strict-dynamic' in the next.config.mjs it
doesn't load some of the client side components and blocks some fetch requests
Question :
1.Which is the correct way to implement it?
2.And will there be a problem when I use the 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' in CSP?

Found any solution? I have same issue here
